# Stored procedure in typeorm returning json response

Tags: sql-server, typescript, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

When I call the stored procedure defined in ms SQL database using typeorm as below,

```
const result=await conn.query('exec Spname @0,@1',[inp1val,inp2val]);
```

At that time getting the response from database but it's comming with some prefix like,

```
{'JSON_F52E2B61_18A1_11d1_B105_00805F49916B':'[{'name':'myname','age':10}]}
```

Why the db result is coming with that JSON prefix. How I can remove this prefix and only populate the JSON object like

```
{'name':'myname','age':10}
```

Comment: Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71574219/edit) your question to include the code of the stored procedure. Almost certainly SQL Server is generating a random name for you because the stored procedure is using `FOR JSON` without returning the serialized JSON in a named column.

Comment: Yes I am using For json auto to get desired output.how I can handle this

Answer (score 0):

Beacuse it is raw response.
Just you can use

```
const result.[0]=await conn.query('exec Spname @0,@1',[inp1val,inp2val]);
```

and result will show

```
{'name':'myname','age':10}
```